# Passport local strategy req.isAuthenticated() is always false

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to setup a login for my new app with passport but I am having some difficulties, no matter what I do `req.isAuthenticated()` is always false. I have tried reordering the middleware as suggested in some other responses to other such questions, but that didn't help, and it already was in the supposedly correct order.
Morgan output:

```
POST /login 302 80.428 ms - 23
GET / 302 0.573 ms - 28
GET /login 200 0.544 ms - 12
```

Here is my code:

```
const passport = require("passport")
const initializePassport = require("./passportConfig")
initializePassport(passport)

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: `http://${REACT_ENDPOINT}:${REACT_PORT}`,
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(flash());
app.use(cookieParser("secretcode"));
app.use(
  session({
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 86400,
      sameSite: "none",
    },
    secret: "secretcode",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I have tried setting the `secure, resave, saveUninitialized` to true and to false, no significant difference.

And here is the passportConfig:

```
function initialize(passport) {
  const authenticateUser = (username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, async (err, user) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: "No user with that username!" });

      try {
        if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
          console.log(user);
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Password is incorrect" });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        return done(e);
      }
    });
  };

  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "username",
        passwordField: "password",
      },
      authenticateUser
    )
  );
  passport.serializeUser(({ id }, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      console.log(user);
      done(null, user.id);
    });
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    console.log(id);
    User.findOne({ _id: id }, (err, user) => {
      done(null, user);
    });
  });
}
```

Both `console.logs` after the bcrypt.compare and within the serializeUser work correctly and return the correct user. However later in my routing:

```
app.post(
  "/login",
  checkNotAuthenticated,
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  })
);

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.send("please login");
});

app.get("/", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.send("logged in");
});

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();

  res.redirect("/login");
}
```

Here within `checkAuthenticated`, `req.isAuthenticated()` is always false. But serialize and `bcrypt.compare` give me the correct User.

I have tried using both `User.findOne` and `findById` no difference between the two.

User model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const User = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```

Comment: In your `checkAuthenticated` middle are can you look at the `req.passport.user` object to see if it was added to the req object? This is what the isAuthenticated function checks against and should be set up after serializeUser is complete.

Comment: @jasonandmonte `req.passport` is undefined, I just checked

Comment: @jasonandmonte also `passport.serializeUser(({ id }, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      console.log(user.id);
      done(null, user.id);
    });
  });` logs the correct user id before `done`

Comment: Also no cookies are being set in the browser

Comment: I don't see anything blatantly off. The only thing I noticed I usually don't see a query in serializeUser since the object is passed from the query in the strategy. You could try simplifying there and possibly adding a callback to  `.authenticate` to see if the user object is being passed.

Comment: @Darkbound Show us your user model.

Comment: @MikiBelavista nothing fancy, I have added it to the main post.

Comment: @Darkbound Read https://levelup.gitconnected.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-passport-local-passport-js-strategy-633bbab6195#ded8

Comment: @jasonandmonte I have already done that and simplified it to just `done(null, user)`